# How to effienctly divide blocks of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I dont even know how to phrase what I am trying to do so I'm going straight to a simple example. I have a blocked array that looks something like this:

```
a = np.array([
            [1,2,0,0],
            [3,4,0,0],
            [9,9,0,0],
            [0,0,5,6],
            [0,0,7,8],
            [0,0,8,8]
            ])
```

and I want as an output:

```
np.array([
          [1/9,2/9,0,0],
          [3/9,4/9,0,0],
          [9/9,9/9,0,0],
          [0,0,5/8,6/8],
          [0,0,7/8,8/8],
          [0,0,8/8,8/8]
          ])
```

Lets view this as two blocks

Block 1

```
np.array([
         [1,2,0,0],
         [3,4,0,0],
         [9,9,0,0],
         ])
```

Block 2

```
np.array([
         [0,0,5,6],
         [0,0,7,8],
         [0,0,8,8]
         ])
```

I want to normalize by the last row of each block. I.e I want to divide each block by the last row (plus epsilon for stability so the zeros are 0/(0+eps) = 0).
I need an efficient way to do this.

My current inefficient solution is to create a new array of the same shape as `a` where block one in the new array is the last row of the corresponding block in `a` and the divide. As follows:

```
norming_indices = np.array([2,2,2,5,5,5])
divisors = a[norming_indices, :]
b = a / (divisors + 1e-9)
```

In this example:

```
divisors = np.array([
            [9,9,0,0],
            [9,9,0,0],
            [9,9,0,0],
            [0,0,8,8],
            [0,0,8,8],
            [0,0,8,8]
            ])
```

This like a very inefficient way to do this, does anyone have a better approach?

Comment: I think you meant to write `norming_indices = np.array([2,2,2,5,5,5])`

Comment: Does `a / a[2::3].sum(0)` return the expected result in the general case?

Comment: I think it might, in my most general case i actually have two rows to normalize by, in that case my norming_indices are `norming_indices = np.array([2,2,2,3,5,5,5,6]`. Which is why i didnt go the slice route. In that case this doesnt work. But maybe i can work with this anyway. Its gotta be better to take 2 sums than to make a whole new array

Answer (score 0):

Reshape to three dimensions, apply the normalization for each block (last row (index `2`) of each 3-row-block (step `3`), then reshape back to original shape:

```
b = a.reshape(-1, 3, 4)
b = b / b[:,2::3].max(axis=2,keepdims=True)
b = b.reshape(a.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.concatenate` may help you

```
    a = np.array([
            [1,2,0,0],
            [3,4,0,0],
            [9,9,0,0],
            [0,0,5,6],
            [0,0,7,8],
            [0,0,8,8]
            ])

    b = np.concatenate((a[0:3, :] / (a[2, :] + 1e-9),
                        a[3:, :] / (a[5, :] + 1e-9)))
    print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[0.11111111 0.22222222 0.         0.        ]
 [0.33333333 0.44444444 0.         0.        ]
 [1.         1.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.625      0.75      ]
 [0.         0.         0.875      1.        ]
 [0.         0.         1.         1.        ]]
```